# Run MySQL client as user without user's password if have root access

Tags: mysql

If importing a SQL dump file using the `mysql` command line client, if it wasn't created by the superuser and guaranteed to not have been modified, for security it's best practice to not execute it as the root user.

I know this can be done using the `-u` and `-p` arguments, but is there a way to not have to know the password for the user if you already have the ability to log in as root (e.g. the root password is in /root/.my.cnf)?  Like is there some way to log in as root then switch to the particular user, or some other easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can put the password for a given user to their `~/.my.cnf` and use only `-u <user>`.

Comment: @jkavalik That sounds like a decent solution if i'm going to be doing it often for the same user, but I'm hoping to avoid having to look up their password altogether.

Comment: you can as well encrypt the password and use that as a string in your command line.

Comment: @tesla747 it would be nice to not have to do anything with the user's password since I already have root privileges.  For example, in bash on Linux if you're root, you can change to any user using `su` without having to know their password.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is not directly possible. The common workaround appears to be specifying the password (and other parameters) in your `$HOME/.my.cnf` as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293090/4126514).

If the job is run from a systemd timer/service where $HOME is not in the environment then you can include the file explicitly with `mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/.my.cnf`. Note that this needs to be the very first argument to `mysqldump`.